# the desktop does not display the folders anymore

Tags: nautilus, desktop-icons

I am new to Ubuntu and Linux in general.

I have just installed some of my first gnome Extensions.

Now I have the problem that the desktop does not display the folders which are in the "Desktop" folder anymore.

I should add that I had to reinstall nautilus to get access to my folders again.

Furthermore there are two new Icons on my Dock. One has to do with the root and the other one is called "efi",

Since I am new a noob I do not know what that could indicate.

Every help is appreciated.

Comment: Your question should list the extensions that you added and other customizations you made. If your install of Ubuntu worked properly, revert each changes until it works properly again.

Answer (score 0):

I had to reinstall ubuntu-desktop because I probably removed it by accident.
I installed it with

```
sudo apt-get install ubuntu-desktop
```